# Why do we need to start the Redis server when it's purpose is to be a database

Tags: redis

Why do we need to start the Redis server when it's purpose is to be a  database, it can be used as in-memory database having different types of data structure but why do we need to start its server.

Comment: Surely any program you want to use you have to start at some point? When you start any kind of computer (server, desktop) the OS doesn't just start every executable at once?

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect?

You want to have somewhere on your network a service that will allow your applications to connect to and save and read data, isn't?

This is what you do when you start a redis-server process, you are starting a process than any of your applications or services can connect to and get access to the data. (this is the case with any database, NoSQL, RDBMS, you do start one or more process allowing you to connect to, and store your data.

Also when you start to use Redis as your database you want this to be highly available and you start to deploy multiple processes (server) on multiple nodes, suing a "master/slave" deployment or even use clustering to distribute your data in multiple nodes for horizontal scalability.